# How increment a number in wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page where i generate a multiple ID's and i put in page, is ads page like that:
[image]

if you see in my page i have that message: The number is: 1 after every ad

I want to increment that number, i try this but i can when de page is in loading my x is alwais 1:

```
<?php 

$x = 1;

if($x <= 5) {   
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x++;
} 

?>
```

I want to increment always in my page 1,2,3,4,5 not always 1, but how can i do

Above i put all my code from page:

```
<?php
global $ae_post_factory, $user_ID;
$place_obj = $ae_post_factory->get('place');
$post = $place_obj->current_post;
// et_location_lat et_location_lng
?>
<?php
$query = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) as featured FROM `eHouTHuQpostmeta` WHERE `post_id`=' . get_the_ID() . ' and meta_key = "et_featured" and meta_value=1');
$date = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT meta_value FROM `eHouTHuQpostmeta` WHERE `post_id`=' . get_the_ID() . ' and meta_key = "et_twitter_url" ');
$hour = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT meta_value FROM `eHouTHuQpostmeta` WHERE `post_id`=' . get_the_ID() . ' and meta_key = "et_google_url" ');
?>
<li <?php post_class( 'post-item' ); ?> >
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="float:left;width:50%">
    <?php if($query == 1){ ?><STRONG>SUGGESTED</STRONG><?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:50%;text-align:right">
        <?php
        if($date != "" && $hour != ''){
            echo "<span id='data-time'>" . $date . "</span>"; 
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
    <div class="place-wrapper<?php if($query == 1){ echo " featured-box"; } ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="img-place">
            <img src="<?php echo $post->the_post_thumnail; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
            <?php if(isset($post->et_google_url) && $post->et_google_url){ ?>
            <div class="cat-<?php echo $post->place_category[0]; ?>">
                <div class="ribbon">
                    <span class="ribbon-content"><?php echo $post->et_google_url; ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </a>
        <div class="place-detail-wrapper">
            <h2 class="title-place">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>         
            </a></h2>
            <span class="address-place">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-map-marker"><span itemprop="latitude" id="latitude" content="<?php echo $post->et_location_lat;?>"></span></i>

                <span itemprop="longitude" id="longitude" content="<?php echo $post->et_location_lng;?>"></span>
                <span class="distance"></span>
                <?php echo $post->et_full_location; ?>
            </span>
                <span class="address-place">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode(get_the_excerpt())); ?>

                 <hr>
            </span>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="rate-it" data-score="<?php echo $post->rating_score; ?>">
            </div>

            <?php 

                if (!empty($post->et_fb_url)) {
                echo "<span class='imageContainer'>&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-usd' style=''>" . $post->et_fb_url . '</i></span>';
                }       
            ?>

            </i>
        </div>

        <?php
        if(@wp_get_current_user()->user_login == get_the_author())
        {
        ?>
        <!--<div class="place-config">
            <i class="fa fa-cog edit-config"></i>
            <img src="http://romanianusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1450310691_6.png" class="edit-config" style="width:22px;height:22px;">
        </div>
        <div class="edit-place-post">
            <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-place?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-history place-remove fa-3x" style="padding-right:50px"></i>
            <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-edit/<?php the_ID(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil place-edit fa-3x" style="padding-right:50px; padding-top:15px"></i></a>
            <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-delete/<?php the_ID(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o place-remove fa-3x" style="padding-top:15px"></i></a>
            <br>
            <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-place?id=<?php the_ID(); ?>"><span style="padding-right:52px">Repost</span></a>
            <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-edit/<?php the_ID(); ?>"><span style="padding-right:52px;">Edit</span></a>
            <a href="http://romanianusa.com/post-delete/<?php the_ID(); ?>"><span style="padding-right:8px;">Trash</span></a>
        </div>-->
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </div>

<?php 

$x = 1;

if($x <= 5) {   
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";

} 
$x++;
?>  

<?php
if (!empty($post->et_url)) {
?>
    <!--<center><span id="flag"><?php echo $post->et_url; ?></span></center>-->
    <center><?php echo $post->et_url; ?></center>
<?php   
}   
?>
</li>
```

Comment: In the second code block, you're always resetting `$x` to 1 before the condition. So it will always be 1. I also don't see any loops in use, but that could just be "because wordpress".

Comment: This page is in loop until doesn;t have id's

Comment: Then the issue is probably that you keep resetting `$x` to be one on each iteration as per the first part of my original comment.